# Conversion of Kinetic energy to electric potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy-conservation, electric-fields

Two deuterium nuclei, separated by a large distance with same initial speed are travelling towards each other; the radius of the nucleus is given. How can I find the minimum speed of the nucleus?

I know that I have to apply kinetic to electric potential energy concept but here both of the nuclei are moving.Since the potential energy is calculated  from a fixed charge ($\frac{kQq}{r}$), how do I apply the equation here?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulas as pictures or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the velocities are not relativistic, the radius in the expression for potential difference is just the distance between the nuclei.